# check if music is played

Tags: objective-c, ios4, avaudioplayer, avfoundation

i use avaudioplayer to play own music in my app. is there a possibility to check if music from the avaudioplayer is playing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the playing property, i.e.:

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer;
if(audioplayer.playing){
   //do what you want here
}
```

Also refer to the [class reference of AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

The class reference states you shouldn't poll this property though. If you want to find out if a song has finished playing, use an `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`. The `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` function will inform you when the audio player finished playing audio.